# HTTPS AUTHORISATION TO THE MAVEN REPOSITORY FAILED

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth:jar:1.0.0.M4: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth:pom:1.0.0.M4 from/to spring-milestone (https://maven.springframework.org/milestone): Authorization failed for https://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/security/oauth/spring-security-oauth/1.0.0.M4/spring-security-oauth-1.0.0.M4.pom 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

WHENEVR RUNNING MY SPRING APPLICATION GETTING THIS ERROR AND BUILD GETTING FAILED ANY ANSWERS WILL BE MUCH APPRICIATED

Comment: Show your <repositories> in your pom.xml please

Comment: Spring repository are not for general usage...fix your build... apart from that why using such an old version...